# Solving two nonlinear ODE's: $ 4(k')^2 - 2k k'' =0$ and $ (k'')^2- 2k' k''' =0 $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How we can solve the following differential equations:

**1)** $ 4 k^{ \prime ^ 2 } - 2k k ^{ \prime \prime } =0 $

**2)**  $  k^{ \prime  \prime ^ 2 } - 2k ^ {\prime } k ^{ \prime \prime  \prime } =0 $

I find that $ ( k k^ {\prime } ) ^{\prime } =k^{ \prime ^ 2 } + k k ^{ \prime \prime }  $ and  $( k  ^ { \prime } k^ {\prime \prime } ) ^{\prime } =k^{ \prime  \prime ^ 2 } + k ^ {\prime } k ^{ \prime \prime  \prime }  $ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two ODE's can be solved using very similar methods.

---

Your first differential equation in Leibniz notation is:
$$4\left(\frac{dk}{dx}\right)^2-2k\cdot \frac{d^2k}{dx^2}=0 \iff 2\left(\frac{dk}{dx}\right)^2-k\cdot \frac{d^2k}{dx^2}=0 \tag{1}$$
We will now treat $k$ as the independent variable, and substitute $v(k)=\frac{dk}{dx}$. This gives:
$$\frac{d^2 k}{dx^2}=\frac{dv}{dx}=\frac{dv}{dk}\cdot \frac{dk}{dx}=\frac{dv}{dk}\cdot v$$
Hence, your ODE reduces to:
$$2v^2-k\cdot \frac{dv}{dk}\cdot v=0$$
You can factor this as:
$$v\cdot \left(2v-k\cdot \frac{dv}{dk}\right)=0$$
Therefore, all you need to do is solve these separately:
$$\begin{cases} v=0 \\ 2v-k\cdot \frac{dv}{dk}=0 \end{cases} \tag{2}$$
Be sure to substitute back for $v=\frac{dk}{dx}$ after solving for $v(k)$.

---

Your second differential equation in Leibniz notation is:
$$\left(\frac{d^2k}{dx^2}\right)^2-2\cdot \frac{dk}{dx}\cdot \frac{d^3 k}{dx^3}=0 \tag{3}$$
Note that you can now substitute $v(x)=\frac{dk}{dx}$ to reduce it to a second-order ODE. This gives:
$$\left(\frac{dv}{dx}\right)^2-2\cdot v\cdot \frac{d^2 v}{dx^2}=0$$
Now, notice that it is in a very similar form to $(1)$. Therefore, we will use a similar method and treat $v$ as the independent variable and let $u(v)=\frac{dv}{dx}$. This will give:
$$\frac{d^2 v}{dx^2}=\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{du}{dv}\cdot \frac{dv}{dx}=u\cdot \frac{du}{dv}$$
Hence, reducing your ODE to:
$$u^2-2v\cdot \frac{du}{dv}\cdot u=0$$
You can now factor it similar to how we solved the first one, and solve them separately like in $(2)$.

Comment: How we can solve (2) ?

Comment: Well, the first one is already solved for $v(k)$. The second equation, you can rearrange as:
$$\frac{dv}{dk}=\frac{2v}{k}$$
Which is a separable ODE:
$$\int \frac{1}{v}~dv=\int \frac{2}{k}~dk$$
This should give:
$$v(k)=c_1\cdot k^2$$
Therefore, you should be solving the following two ODE's:
$$\frac{dk}{dx}=0 \text{ and } \frac{dk}{dx}=c_1\cdot k^2$$